"I wouldn't say I was excited about it" "I wouldn't say I'm excited about it" Which is correct?
When referring to the current situation, meaning the speaker doesn't think they're excited about it.
Are both correct? Or does it depend on the mode (e.g. Written, spoken, casual, formal, etc.)?
Thanks.

Both are fine. There is no "formal context" for litotes (deliberate understatement) - it's a "whimsical, playful" device. In a contrived context, feasibly the Past Tense version might specifically refer to the speaker's lack of enthusiasm at some point in past time, but normally both Past and Present Tense mean the same thing (I am not interested).

...in cases of reported speech or thoughts, the tense is often backshifted.

"I wouldn't say I've been missing it, Bob..."

Is "it" something in the past or present?

Thank you @FumbleFingers and Daniel. Very helpful. I wasn't sure as the present tense sounded more natural even to my non-native ears, yet grammatically I thought maybe it should match the main clause.

The main clause is only "natural" because it's an established convention to cast the statement as a conditional (wouldn't). The truly natural / literal version (assuming we're committed to the litotes! :) is "I don't say I am excited about it", which clearly doesn't allow any possibility of backshifting except in that specific contrived context referred to earlier.


(1) I wouldn't say I was excited about it.
(2) I wouldn't say I'm excited about it.

Both of these are fine. (1) uses the past tense, so you're not speaking about whether you're excited about it now, only whether you were excited about it at some point in the past. You may have changed your mind since then. For example:

I wouldn't say I was excited about it, but I've since warmed up to the idea.

(2) is in the present tense, so it speaks to now. But wouldn't still leaves open the possibility of changing your mind. For example:

I wouldn't say I'm excited about it, but I haven't seen the prototype yet.

